# how to add (associate) a snapshot on a build result

Tags: build, rtc, jazz

a build was created using a build definition - how can i associate (add or append) a snapshot to a build result?

this question occurs because i have some build results and want to create a new repository workspace (or a stream) from an exisiting build result. this workflow is suggested by the context-menu in eclipse

[image]

it always gives me the following error:

[image]

and

[image]

The problem seems to be that there is no snapshot created when i start a build. how can i add a manually created snapshot to that build result or how can i change my build definition that it creates a snapshot automatically?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You first add a repo workspace from the build, as you illustrated i the question.

Then you load that repo workspace in a snapshot (or local sandbox).

You need those two steps.

The [OP Martin Frank](https://stackoverflow.com/users/2910751/martin-frank) explains that the source of the issue comes from having to accept only some of the pending changes.

Workaround: insert a build-setup repository workspace

[image]

you can accept all changes that are required on the 'build-setup' repository workspace. to create a build you use a second repository workspace, namely the 'build' repository workspace. once you have this setup, you can check the option 'Accept latest changes' which will add the snapshot onto your build result.

[image]

Comment: there is no snapshot associated - thats why i get this error message: "you cannot create a stream from the selected build because the build does not contain a snapshot" (the same for creating a repository workspace)

Comment: and hello @vonC - it has been quite a while, nice to see you again =)

Comment: Is there an ownership issue, as mentioned in https://jazz.net/forum/questions/152860/how-to-recreate-a-stream-from-build-result-which-was-created-from-clearcase-synchroniser?

Comment: @ If not, can you try an `scm snapshot promote`, as in https://jazz.net/forum/questions/140870/why-cant-i-promote-the-build-snapshot-baseline-to-stream-in-rtc-when-using-jenkins-plugin?

Comment: @MartinFrank I never left ;) See my two previous comments (I missed the `@` to notify you)

Comment: ok, so you have to set up your build definition with `Post-build Deliver`enabled? - but no snap-shots are created, neither on the repository workspace nor on the stream (which is my deliver target)....

Comment: @MartinFrank No, I usually don't have post-deliver enabled. I just use a workspace which has the right stream as its default flow target.

Comment: @MartinFrank can you try and add a snapshot on your stream, then launch a new build, and see if your can create a workspace or a stream from that build result?

Comment: that's working perfectly - i can manually create a snapshot and set the owner of the snapshot. once this snapshot is created i can easily create a workspace from that snapshot and i can create a stream based on this snapshot. but when i start a build, there is no snapshot created...

Comment: there are already several manually created snapshots on the stream... but theres still no snapshot created on 'request build'...

Comment: @MartinFrank yes, I meant what about a build created *after* setting a snapshot on the stream. Would the build result include a snapshot?

Comment: ok, i've manually created a snapshot on the stream and after that i started a new Build. again, when i click on the build result and want to create a stram/repWorkspace it comes with the same error message - it was expected to be, because again no snapshot was created (only mine manually created snapshot)

Comment: @MartinFrank and can you create a snapshot on the workspace used by the build definition?

Comment: technically yes, although this repository workspace belongs not to me but to our 'build-user' who is managed by my co-worker (so i don't have access directly)....

Comment: @MartinFrank can you try and modify the build definition, with a repo workspace that you own? And with a build engine using your login?

Comment: ok, using a builddefinition which is working on my repository workspace which is run by my build-engine makes no difference - still there is no snapshot created... QUESTION: the only option to 'create' a snapshot is under the tab 'Jazz source control' where you have to select the 'accept options'; only if you accept the latest changes a snapshot is created... but i don't want to accept the latest changes...  i just want to build with all those pending changes pending (i intentionally don't want to build ALL pending changes)

Comment: ok, what did i do? i openend my repository workspace, there i removed the flow targets (after i accepted all desired change sets) and had now a repository workspace with the correct configuration and NO flow targets. then i changed the build definition, i checked the checkbox under Jazz Source Control/Accept Options/Accept latestes changes before loading (wich is kind of useless since my RepWorkspace doesn't have a flow target anymore) and when i request a build a snapshot is created and it is attached to the build result....

Comment: @MartinFrank  "I just want to build with all those pending changes pending" vs. "I intentionally don't want to build ALL pending changes" sound a bit contradictory ;)

Comment: ups - must have mispelled: i want to accept changes manually! i don't want to accept all pending changes automatically....

Comment: well - kind of a workaround, yes... it's working at least even though not very smooth ^^

Comment: i'll accept your answer - all that stuff what happened in the comments finally lead to a solution!

Comment: thank you very much for your support - again it was a hard quest for you and for me...

Comment: @MartinFrank I have edited the answer, and suggest an alternative at the end.

Comment: very nice - that will be more helpful for others, great!!